# Castle Windsor - Registering components

Tags: castle-windsor, windsor-3.0

I have created a common static class for registering components solution wide.

```
private static readonly IWindsorContainer Container = new WindsorContainer();

public static void Register<I, T>() where T : I
    {
        Container.Register(
            Component.For<I>().ImplementedBy<T>().LifeStyle.Transient
            );
    }
```

However, I am not able to compile it. Any ideas?

The type 'I' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TService' in the generic type or method 'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For()'

Comment: And what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Could you provide a test that fails in order to give more insight. If it is needed, I can write a test that proves my answer.

Comment: in the Register method, should it not be T : I, as as T implements I, according to Component.For<I>().ImplementedBy<T>() rather then "where I : T"

Comment: I have updated my question to be more precise  and fixed my earlier typo "I:T".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the warning indicates, `I` needs to be a reference type so it requires a generic constraint to constrain it as such

```
public static void Register<I, T>() where T : I where I : class
{
    Container.Register(
        Component.For<I>().ImplementedBy<T>().LifestyleTransient());
}
```

You may also want to look at using `IWindsorInstaller` types for registering components with the container and then register components with the container using the installers

For example

```
public class MvcInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            // Register HttpContextBase using factory method
            Component.For<HttpContextBase>()
                     .UsingFactoryMethod(() => 
                         new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
                     .LifestylePerWebRequest(),
            // Convention based registration to register all controllers
            // with Windsor
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                   .BasedOn<IController>()
                   .If(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
                   .Configure(c => c.LifestylePerWebRequest()),
            Component.For<IControllerFactory>()
                     .ImplementedBy<WindsorControllerFactory>());
    }
}
```

Then when instantiating the container

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

// find all installers in the current assembly and use them to register 
// services with the container
container.Install(FromAssembly.This());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve registered types you should use the same instance of `IWindsorContainer`.

Types won't be resolved if you use another one instance of `IWindsorContainer`.